# Should i convert all my vars to BigInteger for easier operations

Tags: java

I'm making a game. In this game there is no limit (except technical limits) to money value.
I'm currently using a `long` to store the money value, but the max value is quickly reached.

I found a Java class `BigInteger` but i don't know if it's the best solution because the money value make operations with `long` and `int` values.

Should i convert everything to `BigInteger` to make "easier" operations or is there a better solution?

Comment: Why don't you use a `double`? Or do you want absolute precision?

Comment: I think that [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) is more appropriate for the purpose... Just saying...

Comment: `BigInteger` has no simple arithmetics operations as the primitive types have.

Comment: double max value seems enought.

Comment: @RobertKock Yes it does - but they are method calls so math doesn't read well.

Comment: As some suggest `double` might suffice, but be wary that its precision is limited (and in fact is less than `long`). If accuracy is important `BigInteger` (or similar unlimited precision type) may in fact be necessary. Don't use `double` unless you properly understand how floating-point works.

Comment: (There's certainly no need to convert _everything_ to BigInteger as your question suggests. Only variables whose value range exceeds that of `long` - or possibly `double` if that's a suitable substitute - should be changed to a different type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If money values are bigger than the long maximum value and do not have a decimal part then use BigInteger, otherwise use BigDecimal.